# Adding a minimize button to a Qt dialog?

Tags: c++, qt, qt4

I have created a `QDialog` based app using Qt Creator and all is well other than the dialog has no minimize button. How can I add one? Is there a property in the designer that I can set?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can't add the minimize button yourself as it is handled by the window manager. You can tell the window manager how your dialog should be handled using Window Manager hints. This is done using the [windowFlags](https://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#windowFlags-prop) property of your widget. There's also an [example](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-widgets-windowflags-example.html) demonstrating this.

```
setWindowFlags(windowFlags() | Qt::WindowMinimizeButtonHint);
```

Comment: Thank you!  I trawled through the samples but missed that one.

Comment: The link is broken, the relevant passages should be posted here

Answer (score 7):

Use the [QDialog constructor](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.5/qdialog.html#QDialog)'s [Qt::WindowFlags](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.1/qt.html#WindowType-enum) for minimize.

`Qt::WindowMinimizeButtonHint`