# Qt dialog to main window

Tags: qt, qt-creator, qtwebkit, qtip

I have made a project, in which mainpage is mainwindow while on navigation goes to another page which is a dialog window....now I want the max, min icons on my dialog windows, just like main window but  I am not getting it, I just tried to write  a code in main with dialog.show () but both main window and dialog window are displayed together which should not happen, please can anyone tell me how to add max, min to my dialog window?

Comment: Hi, what is a "max, min icons" ? Some icons you added with Qt Designer in your mainWindow ?

Comment: @Martin I just added the dialog window which has close and other context icon.....I need to add max n minimization to the bar just like a window having it to maximise and minimize, how to do it?

Comment: @Martin I tried to add in main (){mainwindow.show ();dialog.show ()}but it is making both window and dialog to pop up.....which I dont want

Comment: Well, there are two things here. When I create a dialog I have max and min icons on top of the frame. Why don't you have it ? Can you please add a screenshot (or a link to a pic) of what you get ? If you create a QDialog in Qt, you have to understand that it's a new Window. If you want to navigate "inside" your mainwindow, you have to create some widgets inside your mainwindow, not a new QDialog.

Comment: @Martin thank you, I think I made a mistake by adding QDialog inside a mainwindow to navigate, as you told I did something like that to navigate..I will try by adding widgets..if something goes wrong again, I will post a reply with screenshots.thank you

Comment: Have a look at QStackedWidget. It's like a book with some pages. You can define each page with what you want and simply navigate with `setCurrentIndex(...)` function.

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1080876/adding-a-minimize-button-to-a-qt-dialog

Answer (score 0):

This code will helps you to navigate from your dialog to mainwindow even you have hide during navigation.

```
    MainWindow *mainWindow = new MainWindow();
    mainWindow->show();
```

Comment: Its almost 4 years i had added this post.
Btw Thanks sudharshan

Comment: Yes you are correct. But no one give the solution for your question. For the future generation i have posted the answer. thanks raising clear question!